# Override DNS order when conencted to a VPN?

Tags: macos, networking, vpn, dns

I'm having some issues with DNS when I connect to my VPN from my Mac.

When **not** connected, `scutil --dns` (the DNS lookup table) returns:

```
resolver #1
  nameserver[0] : 10.0.1.1
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : Reachable,Directly Reachable Address
```

Perfect. `10.0.1.1` is my wifi router.

However, if I connect to my VPN:

```
resolver #1
  nameserver[0] : 10.8.1.23
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : Reachable,Transient Connection
  order    : 100000

resolver #2
  nameserver[0] : 10.0.1.1
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : Reachable,Directly Reachable Address
  order    : 200000
```

`10.8.1.23` is the DNS server on the network to which I am connecting over VPN. However, notice the `order` parameter: even though **I explicitly set my local DNS as first priority**, the VPN seems to be overriding this by putting its *own* DNS first.

This is particularly annoying, as the VPN DNS is resolving differently than my local DNS (notably, it is redirecting `www.google.com` to `nosslsearch.google.com`).

Is there a way I can override this DNS order, and force my own DNS to always come first no matter what? I still need the VPN DNS in place, however, for when I need to connect to servers within the VPN.

Comment: maybe add nosslsearch.google to your hosts file and resolve it to 216.58.216.142 or another google IP. <- not 100% sure it will work, but it's worth a try.

Comment: True, but that's on a per-host basis. I want *all* network requests to resolve *first* to my local DNS, *then* my VPN DNS. But the VPN DNS doesn't want it to be this way...